# How can Univocity Parsers be used from within JavaFX 8?

Tags: parsing, csv, javafx

How can Univocity Parsers be used from within JavaFX 8?

IntelliJ is being used for this. There are no warnings given by IntelliJ in the coding context, but when running the code there are errors.

Here is the code, and stack trace(abbreviated):

Main.java:

```
package parse;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("parse.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Parse Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller.java:

```
package parse;

import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.RowListProcessor;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private TextArea textArea;


public Controller() {
}

@FXML
private void initialize() {
}

public void print(String message) {

    textArea.appendText(message);
}

public Reader getReader(String relativePath) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath), "Windows-1252");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read input", e);
    }
}


@FXML
public void columnSelection() {

    print("this is the parsing method" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setSkipEmptyLines(true);
    parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter(',');

    // Here we select only the columns "Price", "Year" and "Make".
    // The parser just skips the other fields
    parserSettings.selectFields("AUTHOR", "ISBN");

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.parse(getReader("list3.csv"));

    List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();

    String[] strings = rows.get(0);

    print(strings[0]);


}


}
```

parse.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="279.0" prefWidth="322.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="parse.Controller">
   <center>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#columnSelection" text="Parse" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <top>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
    at parse.Controller.getReader(Controller.java:34)
    at parse.Controller.columnSelection(Controller.java:60)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: That just looks like it can't find the resource. Is list3.csv in the same package as `Controller`, and deployed along with the class files (i.e. to your bin or classes directory, or to the jar file, if running from a jar?)

Comment: That was it, I just had to move list3.csv into the same folder as the  class files, thanks!